# Can I perform a significance test on raw data for a skewed distribution?

Tags: statistical-significance, count-data, skewness

Why should I be concerned with applying a significance test to raw data that indicate a right skewed distribution?

I am not sure if the following info helps: I am faced with data for two samples (n=20) for T4 cell count in two groups (Hodgkins vs non Hodgkins leukemia); the means are 823 and 522, respectively, and the medians are 681 and 433, respectively.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].

Comment: What is it you want to know about these data? Do you want to test if the skew is different from 0? (Why?) Do you just want to test if the means differ from each other, & wonder if the skew is relevant?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the Mann-Whitney U test.  It is a non-parametric test (analogous to the parametric t-test) to determine if one distribution is significantly higher than the other (in this case hodgkins vs non hodgkins leukaemia).  Unlike the t-test, it does not assume normality, and your skewed distribution poses no problem for it.

Answer (score 0):

A t test is fine because it is pretty robust to that violation and errs on the side of being conservative (the true Type I error rate is lower than the nominal one). However, you usually gain power with a transformation such as log or square root that reduces skew. If your browser allows you to run unsigned applets you can see that the test is robust for yourself here: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/tests_of_means/robust_sim.html

Comment: fabulous this helps a bit, but i probably wasn't completely clear as to my query.  My questions are as follows; what concerns should i have for applying a significance test to the raw data of a skewed distribution (apparent on frequency histogram). Secondly what can be done about it?

Comment: I would suggest a transformation to reduce skew, but if you don't choose to and you find a significant difference, it is not compromised by the non-normality. However, you should avoid trying different approaches and choosing the outcome you like best.

Comment: These are count data. A t-test *might* be OK, but isn't the correct test, & there's no reason to make it your first choice.